# Cant figure how to fix this issue in agenda where clicking on a new date renders a part of the previously selected date

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when i select another date that has multiple tasks. The 2nd tasks is rendered from the previously selected date. I suspect that the problem is with how agenda renders item that why im showing my render item function and the agenda code.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og2d2.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTZWv.png)

```
const renderItem = (item) => {
  console.log(item.name)
  const startTime = new Date(item.startTime.seconds * 1000); // Convert timestamp to Date object
  const endTime = new Date(item.endTime.seconds * 1000);

  const startTimeString = startTime.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' });
  const endTimeString = endTime.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' });

  const textDecoration = item.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none';

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={item.id} // Assign a unique key to each rendered item using the task's ID
      style={{ marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 20 }}
      onPress={() => openModal(item, item.id)}
    >
      <Card style={styles.card}>
        <Card.Content style={styles.cardContent}>
          <View style={styles.cardTextContainer}>
            <Text style={[styles.cardText, { textDecorationLine: textDecoration }]}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.cardTextDescription}>{item.description.toString()}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.cardTextDescription}>{startTimeString} - {endTimeString}</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 8 }}>
              {item.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                <Tag key={index} text={tag} />
              ))}
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

```
<Agenda
        items={items}
        markedDates={markedDates}
        theme={theme}
        loadItemsForMonth={loadTasks}
        selected={timeToString(Date.now())}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderEmptyData={renderEmptyDate}
        renderDay={(day, item) => {
          return <View/>;
        }}
        onDayPress={(date) => {
          const selectedDateString = date.dateString;
          setSelectedDate(selectedDateString);
          const selectedMonth = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
          setSubtitle(selectedMonth);
        }}        
        showOnlySelectedDayItems
      />
```